# Java retrieve and compare two dates plus time

Tags: java

Basically I want to ask the user for a date and time of departure then ask the user for time of arrival to compare and  get duration. I was wondering what kind of method of input would be good for this input. I was thinking either a multi drop down box or some kind of scrolling bar type deal. Can any one give me and suggestion on a good input method and what it is called? That does not require adding components or just asking the user to type it in, something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using two dropdown controls (or a calendar control for the date) is a common way of handling this in a GUI.

Search Google for ideas, for example amtrak.com, or any travel website really.